# 4th column in table exceeds the page

Tags: tables

I have the following table in which the 4th column exceeds the page. How am I to fix this problem.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{amssymb,bm}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \bgroup
    \def\arraystretch{2.0}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
    \cline{1-4}
     $\mu \in Y$ & $\widetilde{Q}=\mu P=(r,s)$ & $\mu P \oplus T'$  & $Z(nP)$ \\ \cline{1-4}
    $-4$ & $(339,-6156)$ &$\bigg(\dfrac{4482}{361}\beta + \dfrac{3489}{361}, \dfrac{-52002}{6859}\beta + \dfrac{2057238}{6859}\bigg)$  & $2^{22}\cdot3^{44}\cdot19^{-32}\cdot13\cdot1789\cdot[-46931113911612188165\beta + 242506871209270916181]^2$  \\ \cline{1-4}
    $-3$ &$(6,162)$& $\bigg(\dfrac{-99}{8}\beta + \dfrac{93}{8}, \dfrac{-81}{16}\beta - \dfrac{5049}{16}\bigg)$  & $2^{-32}\cdot3^{34}\cdot5\cdot29\cdot[\dfrac{-143654012463}{2}\beta + \dfrac{596091741497}{2}]^2$  \\ \cline{1-4}
     $-2$ & $(51,108)$&- & $(162\beta + 681,-5994\beta - 24786)$ \\ \cline{1-4}
    $-1$ &$(-21,-324)$& $(-18\beta + 69, -162\beta + 918)$  & $2^{24}\cdot3^{34}\cdot5\cdot29\cdot(95293 +23052\beta)^2$  \\ \cline{1-4}
    $0$ &$\mathcal{O}$& $??$  & $??$  \\ \cline{1-4}
    $3$ &$(6,-162)$& $\bigg(\dfrac{-99}{8}\beta + \dfrac{93}{8}, \dfrac{81}{16}\beta + \dfrac{5049}{16}\bigg)$  & $2^{-32}\cdot3^{34}\cdot5333\cdot97324757\cdot[\dfrac{2188485}{2}\beta + \dfrac{12121421}{2}]^2$  \\ \cline{1-4}
    \end{tabular}
    \egroup
    \caption{Conditions following from lifting the multiplier.\label{condition}}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: (1) Use larger paper. Or (2) put less stuff in the tabular. Or (3) use a different font. Or (4) use a smaller font size. Or (5) reorganise the tabular. Or (6) rotate it (if using portrait currently). Or (7) add `\usepackage{geometry}`. Or ...? There are many ways to 'fix' it. Only you can know which will work best for you.

Comment: You don't need `\bgroup ... \egroup`, by the way. You're in a group anyway. You are either brave or foolhardy using `tabu`. Strongly recommend avoiding it at all costs.

Comment: @cfr took up your advise (2) and (3). My table looks fine now. Thanks. Maybe I was too busy putting lots of stuff in the table, later realized that 2nd column could be deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use geometry package and orientatin as landscape

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[left=1cm,right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{amssymb,bm}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \def\arraystretch{2.0}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
    \cline{1-4}
     $\mu \in Y$ & $\widetilde{Q}=\mu P=(r,s)$ & $\mu P \oplus T'$  & $Z(nP)$ \\ \cline{1-4}
    $-4$ & $(339,-6156)$ &$\bigg(\dfrac{4482}{361}\beta + \dfrac{3489}{361}, \dfrac{-52002}{6859}\beta + \dfrac{2057238}{6859}\bigg)$  & $2^{22}\cdot3^{44}\cdot19^{-32}\cdot13\cdot1789\cdot[-46931113911612188165\beta + 242506871209270916181]^2$  \\ \cline{1-4}
    $-3$ &$(6,162)$& $\bigg(\dfrac{-99}{8}\beta + \dfrac{93}{8}, \dfrac{-81}{16}\beta - \dfrac{5049}{16}\bigg)$  & $2^{-32}\cdot3^{34}\cdot5\cdot29\cdot[\dfrac{-143654012463}{2}\beta + \dfrac{596091741497}{2}]^2$  \\ \cline{1-4}
     $-2$ & $(51,108)$&- & $(162\beta + 681,-5994\beta - 24786)$ \\ \cline{1-4}
    $-1$ &$(-21,-324)$& $(-18\beta + 69, -162\beta + 918)$  & $2^{24}\cdot3^{34}\cdot5\cdot29\cdot(95293 +23052\beta)^2$  \\ \cline{1-4}
    $0$ &$\mathcal{O}$& $??$  & $??$  \\ \cline{1-4}
    $3$ &$(6,-162)$& $\bigg(\dfrac{-99}{8}\beta + \dfrac{93}{8}, \dfrac{81}{16}\beta + \dfrac{5049}{16}\bigg)$  & $2^{-32}\cdot3^{34}\cdot5333\cdot97324757\cdot[\dfrac{2188485}{2}\beta + \dfrac{12121421}{2}]^2$  \\ \cline{1-4}
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Conditions following from lifting the multiplier.\label{condition}}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

define the column as para mode, i.e.

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|p{5cm}|p{5cm}|}
```